# For some reason, the program class is not executing the code

Tags: java

I tried to write code to get the largest prime factor of a big number (in this case, 600851475143). 
After writing four different methods (2 to show results, and 2 with other calculations), I have written the program class, and tried to run it.

When I run it, the result should appear in the console, but nothing shows up. I tried to make the variable that should be printed public, and just print it manually, but it didn't work. Eventually, I wrote the simplest `System.out.print()` command in the main method, but nothing appeared in the console.

I have no idea what the problem is. Does anyone here have a clue?

The class:

```
public class Problem3 {
    public float sum1;
    public float sum2;
    private float num =  600851475143f;

    public void methodGuy(){
        while(sum1==0){
            for(int i=2; i<num/2; i++){
                if(num%i==0){
                    sum1=num/i;
                } else {}
            }
        }
    }
    public void show1(){
        System.out.println("the result of Guys method is: " + sum1);
    }

    public void methodOr(){
        for(int i=2; i<num/2; i++){
            for(float x=num/2; x>2; x=x-1){
                if(i*x==num){
                    sum2=x;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void show2(){
        System.out.println("the result of Ors method is: " + sum2);
    }
}
```

The program class:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Problem3 x = new Problem3();

        x.methodGuy();
        x.show1();
        x.methodOr();
        x.show2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that such a big number `600851475143f` is supported by a variable of type float?

Comment: @nbro if it wouldn't be supported the compiler would tell.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Thanks for pointing out something reasonable :)

Comment: @nbro `float`s can go up to about 3.4 x 10**38.

Comment: @ajb As Absurd said, it probably depends also on the implementation of the compiler...

Comment: @nbro No, it does not depend on the compiler implementation; Java requires that floats be represented in a certain way, and the maximum value is 100% certain to be 3.4 x 10**38 for all correct Java compilers.

Comment: You can't use a `float` for this purpose, because `num` will not be exactly 600851475143.  For more information, go to www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work, ente 600851475143, and click on "Float".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`methodGuy` will never terminate because `int`'s can't get that big.

The largest possible value of an `int` is 2147483647.  If your `int` is that number, and you add one to it, the number will wrap around and become negative.  So after `i++`, the next value will be -2147483648.  Since the loop will continue as long as `i` is less than 600851475143/2 = 300425237071.5, and since `i` will always be less than that, your loop is infinite.

Best would be to make both `i` and `num` have type `long`, instead of `int` or `float`.  Even if you do that, your loop will probably run for a very long time.

In fact, if there are no factors, the loop will be infinite, because `sum` will never be set to something other than 0, and then since you say `while (sum==0)`, the loop will just start over again and do the same thing infinitely.  So aside from the wraparound problem, your algorithm still needs work.

**Further note:** You definitely do not want to use `float` for this, because the number 600851475143 cannot be represented exactly.  The actual value of `num` will be 600851480576.

Comment: Second of all, can doublr represent the number as is?

Comment: @OrN. `double` might work in this particular case, but it's still a bad idea.  There are `long` values that will have too much precision to represent in a `double`.  Basically, when you have a job that requires exact arithmetic using integers, you must not use a floating-point type (`float` or `double`).  And taking the `%` operator requires exact arithmetic--you will get the wrong answer if your numbers aren't exact.  If `int` and `long` aren't big enough, use `BigInteger`.